# Can anything be done if a question doesn't get any answers?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

This may be a noob or stupid question, but still:

I asked a question like 12 hours back on Maths SE and didn't receive any answer. Now that many hours has passed, I am sure that it will never rise to the top list, and will very likely be remain unanswered.

I would still like to get an answer to my question.

Is there anything that can be done in such a situation.

How to get answers for unanswered ones.

**Edit**:
Its a probability question. In case someone is interested in the question. Here is the link:
[Is there any probability model for multi-stage motion of an object such as this.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1829413/is-there-any-probability-model-for-multi-stage-motion-of-an-object-such-as-this)

Comment: Try setting a [bounty](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) on the question.

Comment: @robjohn Thanks, that's a really good idea. Although I just checked the link you provided, it says that minimum reputation needed is 75, and I don't have that being a relatively new user. Anyways, thanks still.

Comment: Some suggestions can be found here: [How to grab users' attention on an old question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3478/how-to-grab-users-attention-on-an-old-question) (And maybe some of the [other posts linked there](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/3478) might be of interest, too.)

Comment: No link to your question provided?

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Hi,just added the link. Previously, I thought may be adding the link will result in more down votes. So didn't add.

Comment: I bountied it, hopefully it will draw more attention on the featured list. You may want to mathjax your expressions. They're simple enough so that I don't think it really makes a difference, but some people skip over questions without mathjax as a matter of principle

Comment: @AlexanderGruber That was so nice of you. Thanks a lot. Will surely pay it forward when I get enough reputation here.

Answer (score 3):

You give the impression that your Question will never be answered if it is not answered within the first twelve hours, which is empirically wrong. Sometimes there are cases like yours where the Question was a "moving target" during those first twelve hours.

You seem to be a fairly new/inexperienced member, lacking enough reputation to offer a bounty, so I recommend (1) working on the problem yourself, and (2) continuing to respond to requests for clarification.

Sometimes Questions get a first Answer after months have passed!

Comment: To add also some data showing that question might be answered later (although most of answers are posted relatively soon): [Distribution of time to first answer in MathStackExchange?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12131/distribution-of-time-to-first-answer-in-mathstackexchange)

Comment: Thanks for your encouragement. Its just that with as more time passes, it gets more unlikely to get an answer, although I get your point. Thanks also for answering the main question on the main Maths SE.